# Convert named-type map[string]string to plain one in Golang

Tags: dictionary, go, types

I have a map of type `set`, which is actually a `map[string]string`. However, passing it to a function which accepts a `map[string]string` fails, because Go does not recognize `set` as one.

However, I fail to convince the compiler it is one. Is there any way to resolve this, without looping and copying?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type name string
type field string

type set map[name]field      // map[string]string after all
type plain map[string]string // also map[string]string

func main() {
    var typed = set{"hi": "ho"} // map[string]string?

    back := plain(typed)  // cannot convert typed (type set) to type plain
    back := typed.(plain) // invalid type assertion: typed.(plain) (non-interface type set on left)

    echo(back)
}

func echo(in map[string]string) {
    fmt.Println(in)
}
```

Comment: Those types aren't equivalent. You can't convert between `map[name]field` and `map[string]string`.

Comment: Yes, that's obvious. Anyways, what's stored in memory is a `map[string]string`, correct? So is there a way to get a `map[string]string` without looping and copying?

Comment: Both error messages clearly state the problem. In Go defining a type like your field is only sensible if you need to attach methods or this type is a major, standalone one. In your code you will have to copy the map.

Comment: No, you need to loop and copy.

Comment: Even if it's the same data underneath? That's sounds like a useless waste of resources?

Comment: Loop and copy it is. If you think this is wasteful: Don't use different types `set` and `plain`. Dead simple.

Comment: Yes, I dislike the different types as well. But this is being done here https://github.com/prometheus/common/blob/17f5ca1748182ddf24fc33a5a7caaaf790a52fcc/model/labelset.go#L28 so I need to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do this using the unsafe package.

Note: I don't think this would necessarily be a good idea, and probably the right way would be to just iterate and copy, but since it does answer the question asked...

```
var typed = set{"hi": "ho"} // map[string]string?
p := unsafe.Pointer(&typed)
var back plain
back = *(*plain)(p)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/yienSuJSnQU

Comment: Okay, wow! I didn't think of `unsafe`. While this is probably a bad way to use, it answers the original question. Thanks!
Nevertheless, loop and copy seems to be the way to go.